# Wso2 identity server i18n turn off encoding HTML?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

wso2 identity server 5.7.  We want to put HTML inside the i18n internationalization files.  Older versions of wso2 (2.0) would present html from those files, but the newer versions encodes the HTML, so it comes out as plaintext instead of markup.

I noticed the java hard codes Encode.forHTML in its functions.
https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/pull/1306/files

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of encoding the HTML content is to prevent Web Application security vulnerabilities such as Cross-Site Scripting (XSS). This can not be disabled OOTB in the WSO2 Identity Server.